# How to create an unsigned integer array in c from the arguments passed to the script?

Tags: c

I need to create an unsigned integer array like

```
char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
char** result    = 0;
size_t count     = 0;
char* tmp        = a_str;
char* last_comma = 0;
char delim[2];
delim[0] = a_delim;
delim[1] = 0;

/* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
while (*tmp)
{
    if (a_delim == *tmp)
    {
        count++;
        last_comma = tmp;
    }
    tmp++;
}

/* Add space for trailing token. */
count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

/* Add space for terminating null string so caller
   knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
count++;

result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

if (result)
{
    size_t idx  = 0;
    char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

    while (token)
    {
        assert(idx < count);
        *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
        token = strtok(0, delim);
    }
    assert(idx == count - 1);
    *(result + idx) = 0;
}

return result;
```

}

```
uint8_t in[] = {0X08,0X3c,0Xe6,0Xe3,0Xb9,0X74,0X4a,0Xdc,0Xd7,0X29,0Xee,0X99,0X35,0X15,0X8a,0X77};
```

from the arguments passed to the script. The arguments will be passed to the script like

```
./conversion 0X08,0X3c,0Xe6,0Xe3,0Xb9,0X74,0X4a,0Xdc,0Xd7,0X29,0Xee,0X99,0X35,0X15,0X8a,0X77
```

I created the following code to create the array from the argument

```
char** tokens;
tokens = str_split(argv[1], ',');
uint8_t hex[100];
uint8_t in[100];

if (tokens)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
    {
            printf("val=[%s]\n", *(tokens + i));

          in[i] = *(tokens + i);

        free(*(tokens + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(tokens);
}

for (i = 0; i < 16;i++) 
 printf("%02x ",in[i]);
```

I am getting the following warning when i executed the script

```
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

But i am able to print out each value using the

```
printf("val=[%s]\n", *(tokens + i))
```

but unable to save this as an array like

Is there anything wrong in my code ? could you please help me ?

Comment: Thank you Jean for your reply. Is there any way to generate the array like so ?

Comment: what would be even better would be a [mcve]. Your `str_split` method is missing so if someone wants to reproduce a working code for themselves, they cannot.

Comment: He doesn't reuse the free()'d pointer that I can see. He's free()'ing char *tokens[i], not char **tokens. Since I is iterated after the free(), it's a different pointer.

Comment: @torstenvl you're right. He was just copying the pointer value (this is the main error), that misled me.

Comment: Sorry Jean, i have added the str_split method now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `tokens` is a pointer-to-pointer type, `char **tokens`. Therefore `*(tokens+i)` is a pointer. You are treating that pointer (to a string) as if it were an integer.

What you need to do is first convert the string to an integer type. `strtoul()` is a good starting point. You can even specify your base so it'll automatically convert from hexadecimal for you.

```
for (i = 0; tokens[i]; i++)
{
    char *endptr;
    unsigned long tmp;
    printf("val=[%s]\n", tokens[i]);
    tmp = strtoul(tokens[i], &endptr, 16);
    if (endptr == tokens[i]) {
        /* end of valid number is the beginning of the string */
        /* that means there was no valid number */
        /* insert error handling here (e.g. reprinting usage) */
        in[i] = (uint8_t)0;
    } else {
        in[i] = (uint8_t)tmp;
    }
    free(tokens[i]);
}
```

Comment: thank you Torstenvl for your reply. could you please tell me what can be done in this to achieve ?

Comment: I don't understand your follow-up question.

Comment: Sorry Torstenvl, let me try with the above

Comment: Thank you Torstenvl for your code, its working :) Thank you so much :)